# prestashop web service

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I want to know the different functions I can call through the web service to deal with prestashop data base, for example the function to add a customer in the database of prestashop!!

Answer (score 1):

You should read the doc : http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Web-service+reference